# "could not translate host name to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" when running pytest on a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, github-actions

I am trying to setup PostgreSQL with my testing files on Docker.

Here is what I have in my `docker-compose.yml`file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  trackr:
    container_name: trackr
    image: trackr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://${HOST}/${DATABASE}?user=${DB_USER}&password=${PASSWORD}"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db_1
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
        - "5433:80"
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
        - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE}
    volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

So as you can see the `container_name` for db is `db_1`. In my `.env` file for pytest, I have

```
'HOST': 'db_1',
'DATABASE': 'dbname',
'DB_USER': 'username',
'PASSWORD':'password'
```

I run `pytest` in the directory, I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "db_1" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

If I change `"HOST"` to `"localhost"`, `pytest` runs perfectly on my machine but exits on GitHub Actions with the error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What could be the issue here?